# TypeError: Invalid url pattern myscheme://*/*: Wrong scheme type

Tags: electron

I've faced with the following error:

```js
mainWindow.webContents.session.webRequest.onBeforeRequest({
    urls: ['myscheme://*/*'],
}, (details, cb) => {
    console.log('onBeforeRequest:', details.url);
    cb({ cancel: false });
});
```

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Invalid url pattern myscheme://*/*: Wrong scheme type.
```

Electron version: 8.2.4

Update: I've tried the following patterns.

```
urls: ['myscheme://*'],
TypeError: Invalid url pattern myscheme://*: Wrong scheme type.

urls: ['myscheme://*/*'],
TypeError: Invalid url pattern myscheme://*/*: Wrong scheme type.
```

Update: I've registered protocols with `registerSchemesAsPrivileged` and `registerStringProtocol`. The same resilt.

Comment: Are you going to receive the url from the deep link request?

Comment: @tpikachu I'm going to catch redirect to deep link.

Comment: app.on('open-url', (e, url) => console.log('open-url', url));

Comment: If you wanna using your method. then like this `myscheme://*` will be enough

Comment: Have you registered the protocol anyhow?

Comment: @tpikachu Yep, I've updated question.

Comment: have you used this to register protocol?

Comment: `protocol.registerHttpProtocol`

Comment: If I register `protocol.registerHttpProtocol` then the handler called as expected. But calling onBeforeRequest with filter 'myscheme://*/*' throws the error: Invalid url pattern myscheme://*/*: Wrong scheme type.